# Unexpected behaviour of regsub with escaped characters

Tags: escaping, tcl

The TCL regsub command seems to behave strangely when I give it strings which include escaped characters.

I have used autoexpect to capture a series of screen displays from an app for which I want to automate testing.  Rather than attempt to use its output as a single block, I am attempting to turn the script generated into series of character strings to improve maintainability.  I've used vi to create a series of fragments, which I then read in one at a time and use as matches with expect.  I do have to do some substitution (for example "^[" becomes "ESC") but I've got to fragment 5, so the idea is generally working. Unfortunately I'm beaten by the substitution of "\[" with "[" in the pattern "xxxx\[[xxxx" (x's are other characters).

I've written a Tcl ascii string dump procedure, and I'm using that here.

```
% ascii_string_dump "\\\[" 0 8 pattern

*** ASCII dump of: pattern (  2 characters) ***
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0000 |    \   [ ... ... ... ... ... ... | 5c 5b .. .. .. .. .. .. |
| 0008 |  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... | .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
% ascii_string_dump "a\\\[\[z" 0 8 test

*** ASCII dump of: test (  5 characters) ***
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0000 |    a   \   [   [   z ... ... ... | 61 5c 5b 5b 7a .. .. .. |
| 0008 |  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... | .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
% 
% regsub -all "\\\[" "a\\\[\[z" "Z" newstring
2
% ascii_string_dump $newstring 0 8 newstring

*** ASCII dump of: newstring (  5 characters) ***
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0000 |    a   \   Z   Z   z ... ... ... | 61 5c 5a 5a 7a .. .. .. |
| 0008 |  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... | .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
%
```

In the above series, I first check that I can create the 2-character pattern "\[".  I then create a pattern which is an abbreviated version of my real problem string, "a\[[z".  Then I submit the regexp and test string to regsub, hoping to replace the "\[" characters with a single "Z".  As you can see, two substitutions have occurred (rather than one) and there is an unexpected "\" at character 2!

Any enlightenment very welcome.  (I've spent a lot of time on this (including writing the ascii dump proc!) but I'm getting nowhere...

Best wishes Allan

Answer (score 1):

This is how regular expressions generally work in most languages.

If you use raw strings, your regsub command would look like this:

```
regsub -all {\[} {a\[[z} "Z" newstring
```

And in regular expressions, `\[` represents the literal character `[` (the `\` is escaping the meta character `[` which otherwise indicate the beginning of a character class).

If you want to replace the string `\[`, then you need to replace a backslash and an opening square parenthesis, represented in regular expressions as: `\\` and `\[`, so your raw regsub becomes:

```
regsub -all {\\\[} {a\[[z} "Z" newstring
puts $newstring
# aZ[z
```

If you want to use quotes, you will need a lot more escaping to do. Each character in `\\\[` will need to be escaped, basically, you need to add a backslash for each one of them:

```
regsub -all "\\\\\\\[" "a\\\[\[z" "Z" newstring
puts $newstring
# aZ[z
```

Or if you can use `string map`:

```
string map {{\[} {Z}} {a\[[z}
```

or

```
string map {"\\\[" {Z}} "a\\\[\[z"
```

should do

Comment: Thank you so much @Jerry! Interestingly your first solution fails though in exactly the same way as mine..```` % regsub -all {\[} {a\[[z} "Z" newstring 2 % puts $newstring a\ZZz % ```` However your double quote solution is fine so I'll proceed from there.  Its interesting that the dump routine shows that I've got the strings right, but something strange is happening in regsub.   Anyway, many thanks for your help, I'm very grateful.  I have a hell of a lot to learn about substitution, as Meatloaf (nearly) sang.  Allan

Comment: @AllanGreen The first one is a representation of what you have, it was not the solution!

Comment: My apologies @Jerry... I thought that the line "# aZ[z" underneath it meant that somehow you'd got it to work... Thanks again though, I'm storming ahead now with my tests!  (the vital clue was to use "string map" rather than "regsub"!)

Comment: @AllanGreen Yea, it's much simpler to use, regex can be a bit more complex if you are not used to it.